# how to convert numeric date and numeric time to datetime column in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgresql, I have table which have two columns lets say date1 (numeric) and time1 (numeric). I want to convert them in date and time as separate columns and then concatenate them to create new timestamp column using select query.

I have data in date1 column like 44473 and time1 column like 18512121, both are numeric cols.

I have used

```
select '1900-01-01'::date+date1::integer,
       to_timestamp(time1::integer::text,'24HH:MI:SS')::timestamp WITHOUT time zone 
from tablename.
```

```
date1        time1
-------------------
2021-10-27   0061-11-04 09:00:00.000
```

Can any one help me out? I know something is wrong with time1 data.

Comment: So what time does `18512121` represent?

Comment: all i know it represent hh24:MI:SS:MS

Answer (score 0):

`18512121` does not contain the character `:` so your format mask for the `to_timestamp` function shouldn't include that. And your input also contains 8 characters not just 6, so you need a mask that includes that.

```
to_timestamp(time1::integer::text, 'hh24missms')::time
```

Comment: return error source string too short for "hh24" formatting field Detail: Field requires 2 characters, but only 1 remain

Comment: @SAH: then your data in the table isn't the data you have shown us. It works fine with 18512121: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=abd208a74b544f8958b6ff8738ca957e

Answer (score 0):

When we correct the formatting string the time is interpreted correctly.

> ```
> create table tablename (
> date1 int,
> time1 int ) ;
> insert into tablename values(44473,1851212);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select 
>   '1900-01-01'::date+date1::integer "date",
>   to_timestamp(time1::integer::text  , 'HH24MISSms')::timestamp WITHOUT time zone "time"
> from tablename;
> ```
>
> ```
> date       | time                    
> :--------- | :-----------------------
> 2021-10-06 | 0001-01-01 18:51:21.2 BC
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ccccb7169a3bf1a825afb71d27e62165)*

Comment: I found out the format actually it is hh24:MI:SS:MS,  so 1851212 should be 18:51:21:0200000. Now when i am converting using to_timestamp(1851212::integer::text, 'HH24:MI:SS:MS')::time gives me 07:03:28 instead. It looks like i will need to use substring? Am I on right path?